# PHPSECLIB Check if connectable

Tags: php, phpseclib

I have a router that takes a RSA token. The unit can often be pingable but not connectable(SSH). I do have a script that checks the ping before gathering the user's token and Connecting to the router to run scripts. PHPSecLib provides the example:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
```

This will fail on not Connectable or Bad login and the user will not know which without using putty.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if ($ssh) {
    exit('Connection Failed');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

phpseclib doesn't actually initiate the connection until you call `login` (or something like `getServerIdentification` or something).

That said, there is `isConnected` and `isAuthenticated`. I think those methods do what you're wanting.